# Recursive jQuery submit function doesn't submit the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, form-submit

I need some code to run right after the submit button has been clicked and before the form has actually been submitted.
I've stripped the code and left only the parts needed to show you the problem.
What I need the code to do is go inside the submit function, but instead of submitting the form call the function again.
The form should submit only in that second iteration.
Except it doesn't. The code is fully executed as it should but the form doesn't submit in the end.

I would appreciate it if someone can explain why.

Here's the code (simplr-reg's the form's name):

```
<script>

var reallySubmit = false;

$(‘#simplr-reg’).submit(function(event)
{    
   if (false == reallySubmit)
   {
      reallySubmit = true;
      $(‘#simplr-reg’).submit(); 
      event.preventDefault();
      return false; 
   }
   else
   {
      return true;
   }
});

</script>
```

Comment: how do u know it wasnt submitted?

Comment: @Neal, I'm working with a WordPress site registration plugin and when the form is submitted I get a message that it was submitted successfully. In this case I don't. I also check the DB to see if a new record has been added.

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#simplr-reg").submit();
```

That says "call the `submit` method on the jQuery selection".  You have a jQuery `submit` handler bound to the selection.  Since you have triggered the event on the jQuery selection, the jQuery handler is also triggered.

If you trigger the event on the native DOM form object (`this` within the submit handler), the jQuery handler will not be triggered, so you won't go round in circles.  Call the [`form.submit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.submit) method:

```
this.submit();
```

Comment: @lonesomeday, thanks. It seems to be working with the code I've shown in the question. But in my full code the first submit function calls another function which at its end I should call the second submit. But it doesn't recognize the 'this' operator there. What can I do?

Comment: @Ash `$('#simplr-reg').get(0).submit();` [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get) retrieves the native DOM element, so you can call the native `submit` method on it.

Comment: @lonesomeday, it still doesn't submit. I've placed the script [here](http://www.mediacoverages.com/newscript/), and would be greatful if you can take a look. The other fuction, called "codeAddress", is in yellow but no need to go through it all. just its end where I call the submit again.

Comment: @Ash Do you get any errors? That looks like it should work, but I'm not familiar with the API you're using.

Comment: @lonesomeday, I've stripped the function to include only the call to the submit function. You can take another look at the code [here](http://www.mediacoverages.com/newscript/). But it still wont submit.

Comment: @lonesomeday, even this simple code doesn't submit:
$('#simplr-reg').submit(function(event) { this.submit(); event.preventDefault(); }); Can you say why?

Comment: @Ash No, I can't. Your problem is elsewhere. Can you show the whole thing, HTML and all?

Comment: @lonesomeday, I've put the entire code [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1eXqlNTQdp8PG7tOZOBfBjwaFeFdcZq4FVKgWuOyzSmk/edit?pli=1&hl=iw&authkey=CIOx4v4F#). A short explanation: It's a PHP file which is a part of the 'Simplr User Registration Form' wordpress plugin. Most of the code I've added is in the function 'simplr_build_form()'. Just look for the word 'ash' in that function. I've also added a few more lines across the file but it's mainly definitions of new fields in the form and writing them to the db. If you need me to put the code somewhere else let me know. Thanks a lot!

Comment: ["Google analytics event tracking"](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/sending-hits#knowing_when_the_hit_has_been_sent) brought me here. Thanks for the answer @lonesomeday.

Answer (score 3):

Change it from a 'submit' event to a 'click' event and attach it to the button itself rather than the form?

ETA: be sure to 'return false' on your non-submit case.

```
$("#simplr-reg-submit").click(function()
{    
      alert("1st iteration");
      $("#simplr-reg").submit();
       return false;
});
```

Comment: It would probably be better for him to add a click event for a button (anything that doesn't automatically submit), and then simply call the form submission event once the other function is done. No need to make it "recursive"

Comment: True enough, but if everything's already created (i.e. autogenerated form), click w/ return false is the way to go.

Comment: @Brian, thanks for the quick reply. Is returning false enough? Shouldn't there also be event.preventDefault(); ? Also, is my syntax correct if the form's name is simplr-reg and the button's name is submit-reg : $("#simplr-reg.submit-reg").click(function(event) ?

Comment: Edited my answer above.  Return false and preventDefault() are essentially the same thing for a submit button.  Return false suppresses the click() event, and preventDefault() suppresses the submit() event.  I would change to an ID if possible, otherwise I believe it's $('[name="submit-reg"]'), but put it in a firebug console to test usage with an ID before it.

Comment: @Ash @Brian In jQuery handlers, `return false` is equivalent to calling *both* `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()`.

Comment: @no.good - stopPropogation() mainly keeps the event from bubbling, right?

Comment: @Brian Right, parent handlers up the DOM will not receive the event.

Comment: @Brian, in your code, why would the second iteration be fired? The first itteration never calls it.

Comment: @Ash - trimmed it up to be a simple .click() without the need for the cases, etc.  The 2nd iteration was from kei's jsfiddle to test if it was firing or not.

Comment: @Brian, great, that's what I thought. Still not sure on the syntax of the button's click function but I'll look it up.